# Machine log detection and removal

Tags: nlp, data-cleaning

I don't know if there's a terminology for the following problem:

Suppose I have a collection of data samples where each sample is a long text. A sample may contain machine logs. The DS problem is to train an ML model to remove the machine log; the machine log could be this long text or very short.

Anyone know if there's a particular name for this NLP problem, perhaps you can send me some references.

I didn't get much luck from searching the term `machine log removal ML` or similar phrasing. I have tried feeding in my question in ChatGPT, and it responded with log analysis anomaly detection (though this is not exactly what I wanted).